# array without size syntax in c++

Tags: c++, syntax

I found this code

```
class item : public slab_item_base {
    version_type _version;
    hook_type _cache_link;
    bi::list_member_hook<> _timer_link;
    size_t _key_hash;
    expiration _expiry;
    uint32_t _value_size;
    uint32_t _slab_page_index;
    uint16_t _ref_count;
    uint8_t _key_size;
    uint8_t _ascii_prefix_size;
    uint32_t _value_size;
    char _data[]; // layout: data=key, (data+key_size)=ascii_prefix, (data+key_size+ascii_prefix_size)=value.
public:
    item(uint32_t slab_page_index, item_key&& key, sstring&& ascii_prefix,
         sstring&& value, expiration expiry, version_type version = 1)
        : _version(version)
        , _key_hash(key.hash())
        , _expiry(expiry)
        , _value_size(value.size())
        , _slab_page_index(slab_page_index)
        , _ref_count(0U)
        , _key_size(key.key().size())
        , _ascii_prefix_size(ascii_prefix.size())
    {
        assert(_key_size <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());
        assert(_ascii_prefix_size <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());
        // storing key
        memcpy(_data, key.key().c_str(), _key_size);
        // storing ascii_prefix
        memcpy(_data + align_up(_key_size, field_alignment), ascii_prefix.c_str(), _ascii_prefix_size);
        // storing value
        memcpy(_data + align_up(_key_size, field_alignment) + align_up(_ascii_prefix_size, field_alignment),
               value.c_str(), _value_size);
    }
....
}
```

Detail here: https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/apps/memcached/memcache.cc#L144

So what does `char _data[]` syntax mean?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: In C this is a "flexible array member". In C++, it's prohibited (but some compilers allow it anyway). It allows you to allocate a struct, and specify an arbitrary amount of extra space to be used for that array. Works reasonably well with `malloc`, not so well with `new`.

Comment: Note that `_data` is the last field in the structure. In C, this kind of struct is usable; in C++ it can only be a pain in the neck, given that there's another member that's not a plain C type, and needs placement-new.